# Why does feedforwardnet(int32(8)) raise an error while feedforwardnet(double(8)) doesn't?

Tags: neural-network, matlab

In MATLAB, `feedforwardnet(8)` creates a feedforward network with one hidden layer containing 8 hidden neurons. MATLAB stores numeric data as double-precision floating point (double) [by default](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html). Therefore `feedforwardnet(8)` is equivalent to `feedforwardnet(double(8))`.

However, `feedforwardnet(int32(8))` will raise the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'ind'.

Error in network/subsasgn>setLayerSize (line 1170)
  err = sprintf('"layers{%g}.size" must be a positive integer.',ind);

Error in network/subsasgn>network_subsasgn (line 180)
        if isempty(err), [net,err] = setLayerSize(net,i,newSize); end

Error in network/subsasgn (line 13)
net = network_subsasgn(net,subscripts,v,netname);

Error in feedforwardnet>create_network (line 116)
      net.layers{i}.size = param.hiddenSizes(i);

Error in feedforwardnet (line 69)
    net = create_network(param);
```

Why won't `feedforwardnet()` takes an `int32` as argument? Equivalently, why doesn't `isposint()` (in *network/subsasgn.m, line 1169)) returns `true` when given `int32(8)` as argument?

The code was tested with MATLAB 2011a, 2012a and 2012b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure which version of the toolbox you have, but the revision 1.7 of `isposint(v)` tests the argument like this:

```
[...]
if ~isa(v,'double') | any(size(v) ~= [1 1]) | ...
  ~isreal(v) | v<0 | round(v) ~= v
[...]
```

which means it will return `false` for everything that is not a `double` or a subclass of `double`.

As for the *"Undefined function or variable 'ind'."* message, my guess would be that is because a bug in the code (the variable `ind` is not created/assigned/passed as argument anywhere in the function).

Comment: Thanks, but what's the point in returning false if the argument is int32 (or int8/int64)? I feel it is weird to reject an int32 saying the function requires an integer.

Comment: I must admit I don't know the author's reason behind the decision of using `isa(v,'double')` instead of e.g. `isnumeric(v)`. Might be that some libraries are tuned for fast execution using double precision floats, and any other numeric type would require converting to double, which takes time. Or maybe the author wanted to avoid the pains of chasing potential bugs caused by mixed integer/floating point arithmetics, and enforced a unique type to deal with. Or maybe this is the Matlab idiom that the author got used with for testing this type of values.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt That's because whenever you do arithmetic with a type other than a `double`, matlab will cast the result back to that type. So for example: `uint16(0.6)*2 = 2` and `class(ans)` will be uint16. So the `isposint` function is testing to make sure its an integer of class `double` probably because some arithmetic is going to be done with it, but it still needs to be an integer.

Comment: Ok, it seems to me that casting int8, int16, int32, int64, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64 to double would be a good idea, although it might cause trouble for large numbers (this could be another reason why they didn't cast).

Answer (score 1):

Edit (at your own risk, not tested thoroughly) `isposint.m` on line 9:

```m
% if ~isa(v,'double') | any(size(v) ~= [1 1]) | ...
if ~isnumeric(v) | any(size(v) ~= [1 1]) | ...
```

Both go through:

```m
a = feedforwardnet(8);
b = feedforwardnet(int32(8));
```

Little change in size:

```
>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class      Attributes

  a         1x1             31224  network              
  b         1x1             30968  network
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I guess the change in size is due to the fact that `int32` is 4 bytes, while `double` is 8 bytes.

Comment: Yes, the point here is that you actually don't gain much in term of memory nor in performance. 
Unless you are really constrained to use `int` I would go for `double`.

Comment: There are no problems casting `int` to `double`, as you can check with `intmax('uint64')` and `realmax('double')`, but you incur in a slight performance penalty.

Comment: Well, doing `double(intmax('uint64'))` you lose in precision. But I agree this is not a big deal unless your network is the human brain ;-)

Comment: Right, got fooled (starts loosing precision at 2^53 while `uint64` is max at 2^64-1).